# Hooking WinHttpReadData to intercept Data

Tags: c++, hook, winhttp, detours

I coded a simple script that sends a request and waits for the response using WinHttp. Now I'm trying to learn hooking and for testing purposes, I want to hook my own script using C++ detour.

I tried to hook the script by reading the data and modifying it within the original hook. However, instead of modifying the original response data, it creates a copy of the data and modifies that instead. As a result, I end up with two responses - the original one that the program uses to react on and a copied modified one that I want to use but which ends up not being used.

I am looking for guidance on how to hook it correctly in order to modify the original response strings code from 2000 to 3000. Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

```
typedef BOOL(WINAPI* PWinHttpReadData)(HINTERNET hRequest, LPVOID lpBuffer, DWORD dwNumberOfBytesToRead, LPDWORD lpdwNumberOfBytesRead);

PWinHttpReadData OriginalWinHttpReadData = NULL;

BOOL WINAPI MyWinHttpReadData(HINTERNET hRequest, LPVOID lpBuffer, DWORD dwNumberOfBytesToRead, LPDWORD lpdwNumberOfBytesRead) {

    // Call the original WinHttpReadData function
    BOOL result = OriginalWinHttpReadData(hRequest, lpBuffer, dwNumberOfBytesToRead, lpdwNumberOfBytesRead);

    if (result && lpBuffer && dwNumberOfBytesToRead > 0) {


        //Replacing a string in the response data
        std::string responseData(static_cast<char*>(lpBuffer), dwNumberOfBytesToRead); //Responsedata then looks like this: {"test", "code": 2000}
        std::string searchString = "2000";
        std::string replaceString = "3000";
        size_t pos = responseData.find(searchString);
        while (pos != std::string::npos) {
            responseData.replace(pos, searchString.length(), replaceString);
            pos = responseData.find(searchString, pos + replaceString.length());
        }

        // Copy the modified data back to lpBuffer
        if (responseData.length() <= dwNumberOfBytesToRead) {
            memcpy(lpBuffer, responseData.c_str(), responseData.length());
            dwNumberOfBytesToRead = static_cast<DWORD>(responseData.length());
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Are you troubleshooting a winhttp issue, or are you trying to learn about hooking in general? If the former, I believe winhttp already has built-in support for tracing.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError both, I'm not sure if that is an issue with winhttp or with the detour hook itself, just looking for help in general